# How to sort a bar plot with specific colors?

Tags: matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to sort the graph with different colors in the same order as the dataframe, but when I sort the values, the colors don't change.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

changelist = (0.1, 0.12, 0.13, -0.1, 0.05, 0.07)
assetlist = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
clrs = ('yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow')

data = {"Assets":assetlist,
        "Change":changelist,
        "Colors":clrs,    
        }
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
dataFrame.sort_values("Change", ascending=False)

dataFrame.plot.bar(x="Assets", y="Change", rot=90, title="Desempeño Principales Activos Enero en MXN", color=clrs)

plot.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `inplace=True` to have the sorting act on the dataframe itself. Otherwise, the function returns the sorted dataframe without changing the original.

Also, you need to give the column from the sorted dataframe as the list of colors, not the original unsorted color list.

(Note that in Python strings need either single or double quotes, and commands aren't ended with a semicolon.)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

changelist = (0.1, 0.12, 0.13, -0.1, 0.05, 0.07)
assetlist = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
clrs = ('yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow')

data = {"Assets": assetlist,
        "Change": changelist,
        "Colors": clrs}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
dataFrame.sort_values("Change", ascending=False, inplace=True)
dataFrame.plot.bar(x="Assets", y="Change", rot=90, title="Desempeño Principales Activos Enero en MXN",
                   color=dataFrame["Colors"])
plot.show(block=True)
```

[image: resulting plot]